# How to combine 2 columns in pandas , both of which are dictionaries, and sort them and store them as a single column (the keys are datetime values)?

Tags: python, pandas

I have one column which looks like this :{'7JAN2021':values...,'28JAN2021':values...}
and another column like this :{'14JAN2021':values.., '28FEB2021':values}

How do i get the final result as: {'7JAN2021':values..,'14JAN2021':values..,'28JAN2021':values,'28FEB2021':values..} as a column  ?

I am currently trying:

```
current_oc=pd.read_csv('data1.csv',parse_dates=['Date'],index_col='Date')
next_oc=pd.read_csv('data2.csv',parse_dates=['Date'],index_col='Date')
current_oc['Prices']=current_oc['Prices'].str.replace("'",'"').apply(lambda x:json.loads(x)) #converts the string to dictionary
next_oc['Prices']=next_oc['Prices'].str.replace("'",'"').apply(lambda x:json.loads(x)) #converts the string to dictionary
next_oc['Prices1']=next_oc['Prices'].update(current_oc['Prices']) #combines the 2 dictionaries 
print(next_oc)
```

This is what is being returned:

```
                        Prices
Date                      
2021-01-01 09:16:00   None
2021-01-01 09:17:00   None
2021-01-01 09:18:00   None
2021-01-01 09:19:00   None
2021-01-01 09:20:00   None
...                    ...
2021-01-01 15:25:00   None
2021-01-01 15:26:00   None
2021-01-01 15:27:00   None
2021-01-01 15:28:00   None
2021-01-01 15:29:00   None

[374 rows x 1 columns]
```

I have also tried the following in place of the last line:

```
next_oc['Prices1']=next_oc['Prices'] | current_oc['Prices']
```

This is what i am getting:

```
                     Prices
Date                       
2021-01-01 09:16:00    True
2021-01-01 09:17:00    True
2021-01-01 09:18:00    True
2021-01-01 09:19:00    True
2021-01-01 09:20:00    True
...                     ...
2021-01-01 15:25:00    True
2021-01-01 15:26:00    True
2021-01-01 15:27:00    True
2021-01-01 15:28:00    True
2021-01-01 15:29:00    True

[374 rows x 1 columns]
```

Edit: Both the columns have the same index values

How do i get the final result as: {'7JAN2021':values..,'14JAN2021':values..,'28JAN2021':values,'28FEB2021':values..} as a column  ?

Comment: can you format your sample data? it's incomprehensible atm

Comment: I guess you should read the doc of `pandas.concat`